# Check between two dictionary type value columns to assign label

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'api_spec_id': [117455, 117455, 117455, 117456, 117456],
    'commit_date': ['2023-06-01', '2023-06-02', '2023-06-03', '2023-06-01', '2023-06-02'],
    'diff_2': [
        [{
            "id": "response-media-type-removed",
            "text": "removed the media type 'application/json' for the response with the status '400'",
            "level": 0,
            "operation": "GET",
            "path": "/continuous/filters"
        },
        {
            "id": "response-media-type-removed",
            "text": "removed the media type 'application/json' for the response with the status '406'",
            "level": 0,
            "operation": "GET",
            "path": "/continuous/filters"
        },
        {
            "id": "response-media-type-removed",
            "text": "removed the media type 'application/json' for the response with the status '501'",
            "level": 0,
            "operation": "GET",
            "path": "/continuous/filters"
        }],
        [],
        [],
        [{
            "id": "response-media-type-removed",
            "text": "removed the media type 'application/xml' for the response with the status '200'",
            "level": 0,
            "operation": "GET",
            "path": "/continuous/filters"
        }],
        []
    ],
    'nonBreakingChanges': [
        {
            "api title added": 0,
            "api title modified": 0,
            "api description added": 0,
            "api description modified": 0,
            "api version added": 0,
            "api version modified": 0,
            "api contact deleted": 0,
            "api contact added": 0,
            "api contact modified": 0,
            "api license deleted": 0,
            "api license added": 0,
            "api license modified": 0,
            "server deleted": 0,
            "server added": 0,
            "server modified": 0,
            "path added": 0,
            "path parameter added": 0,
            "path parameter deleted": 0,
            "path parameter modified": 0,
            "desc schema property of resp": 57
        },
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {
            "api title added": 0,
            "api title modified": 0,
            "api description added": 0,
            "api description modified": 1,
            "api version added": 0,
            "api version modified": 0,
            "api contact deleted": 0,
            "api contact added": 0,
            "api contact modified": 0,
            "api license deleted": 0,
            "api license added": 0,
            "api license modified": 0,
            "server deleted": 0,
            "server added": 0,
            "server modified": 0,
            "path added": 0,
            "path parameter added": 0,
            "path parameter deleted": 0,
            "path parameter modified": 0,
            "desc schema property of resp": 0
        }
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Every id has multiple commit dates so I want to iterate over all the commit dates and essentially do this:

I have two columns `diff_2` and `nonBreakingChanges` through which I want to create a new column `type` based on four conditions:

first if `diff_2` and both `nonBreakingChanges` have values and are not empty it gets assigned `Both`

if only `diff_2` has values then assign `B` ( in this case the other column can be either {}, [], NaN or empty string)

if `nonbreakingChanges` has values present then assign `NB` (in this case the other column can be either {}, [], NaN or empty string)

I am not sure how this can be possible with dictionary type of data, any suggestions or ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

def assign_type(row):
    diff_2 = row['diff_2']
    nonBreakingChanges = row['nonBreakingChanges']
    
    if diff_2 and nonBreakingChanges and diff_2 != [] and nonBreakingChanges != {}:
        return 'Both'
    elif diff_2 and diff_2 != []:
        return 'B'
    elif nonBreakingChanges and nonBreakingChanges != {}:
        return 'NB'
    else:
        return None

df['type'] = df.apply(assign_type, axis=1)
```

This code defines a function `assign_type` that takes a row from the DataFrame as input. It checks the values of `diff_2` and `nonBreakingChanges` according to the specified conditions and returns the corresponding type. The function is then applied to each row of the DataFrame using the `apply` function with `axis=1` to iterate over rows.

The resulting DataFrame `df` will have a new column called 'type' containing the assigned types based on the conditions you provided.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow.  It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since both of your recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use .loc

```
df['type']="None"
df.loc[(df['diff_2'].apply(lambda x:len(x))!=0) & (df['nonBreakingChanges'].apply(lambda x:len(x))!=0),'type']="Both"
df.loc[(df['diff_2'].apply(lambda x:len(x))!=0) & (df['nonBreakingChanges'].apply(lambda x:len(x))==0),'type']="NB"
df.loc[(df['diff_2'].apply(lambda x:len(x))==0) & (df['nonBreakingChanges'].apply(lambda x:len(x))!=0),'type']="B"

print(df)
```